# Powershell test-connection hangs

Tags: powershell

I am experiencing a problem running the Test-Connection command from one of my scripting servers.  Simply running the command `Test-Connection -ComputerName $Hostname -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop` hangs the powershell session.  Running the ping command works as expected.  The issue is specific to this one server I am running the command from.  Other servers are running the command and returning the expected values.  I know about Test-NetConnection and this works, however, I need to know the root cause why Test-Connection is hanging on this one server.  Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add the description of the issue?

Comment: It times out for me in 4 seconds with microsoft.com.  Note that -erroraction stop would terminate a script.  What did you do before it?  bug:  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11418

Answer (score 0):

`Test-NetConnection` is the successor of `Test-Connection`, it adds a few functionalities like port availability check and `tracert` functionality.

I would need to see the exact error to know if it is in fact a timeout issue, if so the default timeout for `Test-Connection` must be lower than `Test-NetConnection` or maybe its because `Test-Connection` uses only ICMP (Internet Control Message Protocol) and `Test-NetConnection` even though it can use this protocol if asked by parameter may not use it as the default protocol.

Comment: Part of the problem is there is no error message, just hangs the session.

Comment: uhh weird, anyway according to Microsoft `Test-NetConnection` should be used over `Test-Connection`. if this helped consider accepting this as the response.